# How can I create two jar files with different classes using pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I'm new to Maven and using POM.XML to create jar files.

What I have right now is three jar files being generated, all without their dependencies. For example one of my dependencies is Selenium, which I use to open a chrome browser.

What I need is two jar files, each with their dependencies.

I've tried making a single jar file with it's dependancies, which works. Here is the code for that...

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.costanzo.mavendemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-archive</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.costanzo.mavendemo.MavenDemo1</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> 
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

But when I try adding an another execution to generate another jar file, it creates three, all without my dependencies.

```xml
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.costanzo.mavendemo.MavenDemo1</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <classifier>client</classifier>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly2</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <classifier>client2</classifier>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Now, please note that I've added a version inside my build tag. This forced me to change my 'goal tag' from 'single' to 'jar'. I've also tried sticking the dependencies such as the whole 'configuration' tag from the original into both of the executions. I am getting three jar files, but none of them include the dependence.

*** Edit ***
I know it would be better to split this .xml into more than one file to complete this task, however the specifications of the project dictate they must be done using one pom.xml file.

Comment: Make separate modules...

Comment: I am new to using XML in java. Is a module a specific tag, or do you mean modular the code into two different pom files.

Comment: in the second snippet you pasted, is shows maven-jar-plugin instead of maven-assembly-plugin, is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo. I was looking online and I must have been looking at a different version becasuse the code would not compile without changing that.